# OpenBSD. etherip tunnel do not makes connection

Tags: routing, openbsd

I try to create a tunnel through etherip. And I did read man pages  [etherip in OpenBSD](http://man.openbsd.org/etherip.4). But this example aren't working in my servers.

```
cat /etc/sysctl.conf
net.inet.etherip.allow=1
net.inet.ip.forwarding=1


cat /etc/hostname.etherip0
tunnel 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.1
up

cat /etc/hostname.rl2
inet 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.0

cat /etc/hostname.rl0
up

cat /etc/hostname.bridge0
add rl0
add etherip0
up link2
```

The other side is almost the same, with a few differences.
Output from tcpdump

```
tcpdump -i rl2 proto 97
tcpdump: listening on rl2, link-type EN10MB
16:29:20.167386 etherip 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.2 ver unknown len 62 [tos 0x10]
16:29:20.212008 etherip 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.2 ver unknown len 108 [tos 0x10]
16:29:20.215037 etherip 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.2 ver unknown len 62 [tos 0x10]
16:29:20.482914 etherip 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.2 ver unknown len 108 [tos 0x10]
16:29:20.504005 etherip 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.2 ver unknown len 93 [tos 0x10]
16:29:20.504073 etherip 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.2 ver unknown len 93 [tos 0x10]
16:29:20.504099 etherip 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.2 ver unknown len 93 [tos 0x10]
```

I don't see what is wrong. Why don't work etherip tunnel?